# An infinite loop while using Scanner - java

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I want to ask the user whether he wants to create a file named `file.elt` or not. I'm trying to do this with a switch statement using `Scanner` class.

**Here is my code:**

```
    System.out.println("Do you want to create the file.elt? (Y/N)");
            strOption=sc.nextLine();

        OUTER:
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            switch (strOption) {
                case "Y":
                case "y":
                    elements.createElements(file);
                    break OUTER;
                case "N":
                case "n":
                    System.out.println("There will be no file.elt created! .");
                    break OUTER;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please, type Y or N.");
                    strOption=sc.nextLine();
                    break;
            }                
        }
        sc.close();
```

The `sc` object is declared at the beginning of the program, where I ask for the name of the file.

**The `sc` declaration is:**

```
    String file;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type the name of the file .dat .");

    file=sc.nextLine();
```

The problem is that the while loop is infinite and I don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not updating `strOption`.
You should move your `strOption=sc.nextLine();` inside  your `while` loop
Also, as TheLostMind pointed out, replace `hasNext` with `hasNextLine`.

---

*Edit*

You might consider to switch to [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html). Also, you may create `confirm` utility method since  it's fairly common task:

```
private Console console;

...
console = System.console();
...
if (confirm("Do you want to create the file.elt? (Y/N)")) {
    elements.createElements(file);
} else {
    System.out.println("There will be no file.elt created! .");
}
...

private boolean confirm(String message) {
    String answer = console.readLine(message);
    while (!answer.matches("[YyNn]")) {
        answer = console.readLine("Please, type Y or N.");
    }
    return "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer);
}
```

Note: This [doesn't work in eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429).

Comment: Also change `sc.hasNext()` to `sc.hasNextLine()`

Answer (score 1):

Scanner is state based, and a bit difficult. I would not use it for non-token things.

```
//strOption=sc.nextLine();
OUTER:
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    strOption=sc.nextLine();
...
        default:
            System.out.println("Please, type Y or N.");
            //strOption=sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

1. Because `sc.hasNext()` is always true . you need to call `sc.nextLine` to advances this scanner past the current line
2. `sc.hasNext()` is blocking (as describe in the [documents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) )

if you cn tell if it's realy an infinite loop or blocking call - you will know how to solve it (simply add trace at the beginning of the loop , run the program , and check the output console )

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use labels such as `OUTER` unless you know what you are doing. In this case it is not needed.

`sc.hasNext()` returns true (otherwise you wouldn't even enter the loop) and in the loop you don't do anything to change that state (you don't 'consume' the inputstream).

Before you even enter the loop, you read the first line, after which there is apparently more input to be read but you never read that input so `sc.hasNext()` keeps returning true and the while loop never finishes.

Your `break OUTER;` breaks to the loop defined in `OUTER:`, which means it breaks TO the while loop, <del>not OUT of the while loop. Typically people use this construct to break out of an inner loop to an outer loop but as I said before, you're better of not using this construct.</del>

EDIT: I confused labeled breaks with labeled continues. Basically, the break here works as intended but the label is superfluous (and I still advise against using labels).

The problem then is that the first line of input you read probably didn't equals a "y", "Y", "n" or "N" for some reason and since you don't consume the input, `sc.hasNext()` and `strOption` still contains the same string which doesn't equal any of your case statements, meaning the loop will go on infinitely.

<del>Either use a plain `break;` or</del> fix your loop so it consumes the input.

For example:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to create the file.elt? (Y/N)");

while (sc.hasNext()) 
{
    String inputString = strOption=sc.nextLine();
    // handle inputString          
}
sc.close();
```

Comment: The break with label breaks *to* the outer loop, but since the outer loop immediately ends, it is in most cases equivalent to a break *out* of the outer loop. (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

Comment: thanks for your tip! In fact, I have never used labels before...thank u! As you can see, I'm quite new in java programming.

Comment: @ThomasStets You are correct. I confused labeled breaks with labeled continues.